# Doubt in Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, field-calculator, latitude-longitude, decimal-points

I am working in an project.I have a point Shapefile its projection is **NAD83(HARN)Pennslyvaniasouth(ftUS)****EPSG3365** when I measure its distance(between two points) it gives me the answer in feet .yes its acceptable for me.I also calculated its x-coordinate and y-coordinate for the points in field Calculator it displays me the answer in feet.This is the problem.In my company they are insisting me to show the LAT-LONG value in Decimal Degrees.Is it possible to show the Lat-long in Decimal degrees in QGIS?

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly you're trying to do. What do you mean by "calculated its lat-long"? What expression did you use in the field calculator? Do you simply want the geographic coordinates (latitude/longitude) for all the points in your layer?

Comment: @Jake let me properly explain "calculated its lat-long" means i calculated X-coordinate($X) and y-coordinate($Y) in field calculator. I am getting ($X ,$y) in feet but I want this in Decimal Degree.Is it possible to get in QGIS  I am asking?

Comment: For that, you need to project your layer to a geographic coordinate system first: Select the layer, click "Layer / Save as", then choose a geographic CRS such as EPSG:4326. Then use the field calculator on this new layer to get the coordinates in latitude/longitude.

Answer (score 1):

I think **transform()** function was not available when the question was posted (Y2013).

Now we can solve this CRS issue, just by the Field Calculator!

For Longitude: ......  `x(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:3365', 'EPSG:4326'))`

For Latitude: .........   `y(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:3365', 'EPSG:4326'))`

I created three random points near Philadelphia, and the **transform()** worked as expected. (Imported to GoogleEarth as KML and made a visual check).

[image]